# Convert attributes to values with selective preservation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entity Type="defect">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="user-28"/>
    <Field Name="user-29">
      <Value>1</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="has-change">
      <Value></Value>
    </Field>
    ...
```

I am trying to convert this so that all `Field` elements become elements with the `Name` attribute converted to an element, and that it drops the `Fields` element. So far I have partial success using the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
              indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Entity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It results in the following, which is partly right, but it loses the `Type` attribute on the `Entity` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entity>

    <user-28/>
    <user-29>1</user-29>
    <has-change/>
```

An additional complication is that I need this to work on the following document as well, which contains an `Entities` root node with multiple `Entity` nodes, without losing the root node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entities TotalResults="60">
  <Entity Type="defect">
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="id">
        <Value>1161</Value>
      </Field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:copy>` only copies a node itself, none if its attributes or child nodes. Applied on attributes, it copies the complete attribute, i.e. name and value.

When doing a transformation that preserves most of the document, it's a good idea to use an identity transform template.  What about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- We don't want to copy <Fields>, just the contents -->
  <xsl:template match="Fields">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see this post until after I had already posted my answer; I didn't intend to replicate what you had posted 1 minute prior. :)

Comment: It works, thanks! And now I understand what is happening in the XSLT a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Please see the slight changes in my answer below.

**When this XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Fields">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Field">
     <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
       <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the 1st provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entity Type="defect">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="user-28"/>
    <Field Name="user-29">
      <Value>1</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="has-change">
      <Value/>
    </Field>
    <!-- other <Field> elements -->
  </Fields>
</Entity>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Entity Type="defect">
  <user-28 />
  <user-29>1</user-29>
  <has-change />
  <!-- other <Field> elements -->
</Entity>
```

**If this same XSLT is run against the 2nd provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entities TotalResults="60">
  <Entity Type="defect">
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="id">
        <Value>1161</Value>
      </Field>
      <!-- other <Field> elements -->
    </Fields>
  </Entity>
</Entities>
```

**...again, the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Entities TotalResults="60">
  <Entity Type="defect">
    <id>1161</id>
    <!-- other <Field> elements -->
  </Entity>
</Entities>
```

**Explanation:**

- The first template is [`The Identity Transform`](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html). As you can probably surmise, its purpose is to, by default, copy all nodes and attributes from the source document to the result document as-is.
- The second template matches all `<Fields>` elements. Upon finding one, the XSLT parser is instructed to apply templates to its child elements (which, additionally, has the effect of removing that `<Fields>` element).
- The final template is the same as the one you already had.

Comment: Thanks! You and Thomas W posted within seconds of each other, both with the correct answer. I wish I could accept both :-(

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to help.